# Can I Mine with The Linux OS that I use To Already Mine With?

Tags: mining, ether

I am thinking of starting to mine ETH or try in the next day or so. I use a version of BAMT i customized and upgraded to mine some of the latest currencies that have been released. I have checked using a mining calc that I would actually make some coins with my rig.

1. Can I use BAMT to mine ETH?
2. If so, what settings etc.. do I need to use/switch to? I will be using a pool to mine. Also I read that the algo that ETH uses is memory based while my current mining I OC'd the GPU which gives me a better hash rate
3. with ETH do I need to lower the GPU core speed and then increase the memory?

The current coin I mine uses the core proc power so I lowered the memory.

Comment: it's way better to separate questions as it will be easier for future users that might have the single same issue to find answers

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can mine with any OS as long as you got a miner. I don't know what bamt is based on, [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=bamt) didn't return anything.

Your best bet if it's not a Ubuntu derivative is to compile by yourself the [C++ branch here](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella), you'll find numerous recipes here and in the Homestead docs, there's no point in rewriting them.

Your hashrate will also be better if you overclock, just make sure you get enough RAM in your GPU to handle the DAG, 2Gb cards might soon not be able to load it.